# Long running workflow in .NET 4.0 problem adding required references

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, .net-4.0-beta-2

I am attempting to complete the following "how-to" in order to try and understand how persistence works in .NET 4.0 Workflows.

[MSDN - How to: Create and Run a Long Running Workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489452(VS.100).aspx)

Unfortunately, there seems to be an error in the documentation or I have a problem with my setup, as I am unable to add references to the following components:

- System.WorkflowServiceModel
- System.WorkflowService

These components are specified in step (1) of the section "To enable persistence in a workflow application".

I tried researching this problem but didn't find anything very useful. It seems that I'm not the only person who has had problems:

[Microsoft Connect - VS2010 Missing Assembly System.WorkflowServiceModel](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=453853&wa=wsignin1.0#tabs)

A user here suggests that "the problem was that the client profile was used" but I don't really understand what this means.

I have added my question to that page and will update here if an answer is forthcoming from Microsoft.

**Update:**

Following Chris' comments, I found a better link which I put in a comment. I think the accepted approach on Stack Overflow is to update the initial question?

[MSDN - Configuring the SQL Workflow Instance Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee395773(VS.100).aspx)

Comment: Check your project properties to see what .NET framework version you are targeting.  Many projects by default target what's called the .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile.  For workflow services, you want to make sure that you're targeting the regular .NET Framework 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the documentation, not a problem with your setup.  Actually, the whole article seems to contain completely outdated information - almost none of the content seems to be related to WF Beta 2.  I would suggest looking up another site for now.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I have found a better link:

Configuring the SQL Workflow Instance Store
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee395773(VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The assembly(ies) got [renamed/reorganized some time between PDC 2008 and Beta1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wfprerelease/thread/95afa0e3-7525-43e8-bed8-c58855dcfbb7). Look for System.ServiceModel.Activities.